# Detect whether the text content has CDATA

Tags: java, xml, cdata

I have two api for getting a description of apps and one common UI. I need to check whether the description come with `CDATA` tag or not in Java.

For example, one app has the following description :

```
"<![CDATA[<p>What is Skype?<br />Skype is software that enables the world's     
conversations. Millions of individuals and businesses use Skype to make free video and voice    
calls, send instant messages and share files with other Skype users. Everyday, people also    
use Skype to make low-cost calls to landlines and mobiles.</p>]]>"
```

And another app has the following description

```
Run with your fingers as fast as you can to try and get to the top of the leader board. This    
 game gets even better with friends, Once people see you playing they will want to have a go    
 and try to beat your fastest time. Tip: Take long strides on the screen to get maximum     
distance per step,     
<a href=https://abc.defgh.ij.kl/apps/wap/shopping/shopping/freshima-supermarket/freshima-supermarket/web/>WAP URL</a>
```

How can I differentiate there two description? Is there a way to detect whether the description comes with `CDATA` or not in Java?

Comment: Why does it matter? Either it will use CDATA or it will use entities (or it won't have characters where either are needed). Whatever XML library you use should handle it transparently.

Answer (score 3):

How are you parsing your XML?

If you are using **StAX**, you can get the current event that you encounter in your stream, which might be `XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS` or `XMLStreamConstants.CDATA`.

If you are getting a `Node` Object (like for instance via **XPathAPI**), the Object will offer you a `getNodeType()` Method. Also `Node` has Constants for `Node.TEXT_NODE` and 
`Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE`.

More Information would be helpful answering your question.

Regards,
Max

Answer (score 0):

You should not be treating the following two examples differently, because as far as XML is concerned, they are just different ways of escaping the same content:

```
<a><![CDATA[<xyz/>]]></a>

<a>&lt;xyz/&gt;</a>
```

So perhaps your test is simply "does the text content contain a `<` character?".