# how to check that XML element contains CDATA?

Tags: java, xml, cdata

i am parsing a XML file in java. How can I know whether the emelent contains CDATA or not? In other words how to identify elements containing CDATA?Thanks

WL

Comment: You mean `<[![CDATA ... ]]>` sections? There is no way to detect them, but lucky for you there is also absolutely no need to detect them.

Comment: Some parsers do expose CDATA blocks (although I couldn't name one off the top of my head) … but as Tomalak says, you should never need to care.

Comment: then how can I get the value of that element. with on CDATA section I can get it like nl.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(). where nl is nodelist but I cant get it where CDATA is involved. help please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect whether the text content has CDATA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999089/detect-whether-the-text-content-has-cdata)

Comment: Infact I am opening a xml file and make some changes if required and then save it back in same file or new file. while parsing i can get data even involiving CDATA by applying documentBuilderFactory.setCoalescing(true) on whole file but when I write it back then I need to know which elements were having CDATA so that I can write the file back accordingly. Any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: @waqas: Why? Write them back without the CDATA, where is the difference?

Comment: @Tomalak: Or just write them all with CDATA, it certainly won't hurt anything.

Comment: infact problem is I am using sql queries in it. And if I use without cdata then those signs like < or > can confuse parser and parser can take it as new element but infact it is for greater than or less than for sql query.

Comment: @waqas Not true. If that parser understands XML it will convert the `&lt;` back to `<` before using the node value, you won't even notice.

Comment: yeah true but for that we need to use &lt instead of <. so we can use use < using cdata but not without cdata. so what if I want to use < directly using cdata. so any suggestion how to handle it?

Comment: How are you parsing your XML? Maybe my answer on that other thread helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9000683/1143392. Good luck, Max

Answer (score -3):

You will have to read the text of the tag then find if CDATA exists within the text with a string contains or the like. Kind of like:

```
String cdata = data.text("xmltag");
cdata.contains("cdata")....
```

Comment: 'cdata' tag is omitted while saving it to database, but the content is preserved. So you can't really check if the string has cdata tag as it will never have

Comment: Down vote? The question doesn't ask about a database, only parsing a file.

Comment: @jasonflaherty If you use an XML parser like DOM and obtain the InnerText property value, you get text from which whitespace is either stripped or not, depending on whether the content was enclosed in a CDATA section or not, but you will never know if it was because you only get the content of a CDATA section. Your method only works if you read and parse the raw XML yourself and not many people use XML that way.